# Work with handles in autoitx4java

Tags: java, handle, autoit

I work with [autoitx4java](https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/) in my java project.

That works fine until the window title I work with exists multiple times.

Imagine I have three windows with the title "MyAppTitle" open:

```
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
int posX = x.winGetPosX("MyAppTitle");
```

Obviously a single value is returned. And it's the x-pos of the window "MyAppTitle" that I focused last.

It's no problem to get the handles of the windows. But most of the methods autoitx4java provides require the window title as parameter.

How can I access the windows with their handle? Or is there a better library I could use?

**UPDATE:** From the official AutoIt website:

> When you have a handle you may use it in place of the title parameter
>   in any of the function calls that use the title/text convention.

But it doesn't work within the autoitx4java library.

Comment: It looks like winGetHandle is returning a String anyway, can you use the string representation of the handle returned by that.

Comment: As I said, the methods require the window title as parameter. It doesn't work when I pass the handle. I see no way to work with the handles.

Comment: You may have to invoke AutoItX directly then, I've never used Java, but looking at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/source/browse/src/autoitx4java/AutoItX.java), there is a method `winVariantBool` that calls the method in the ActiveX component. The best approach may be to add overloads to the class for all the functions allowing it to take handles instead of titles.

Comment: Don't know if this is going to be of any help to you! autoitx4java uses something called JNI, which is not exactly user-friendly. There is another way to hook up Java + AutoIt, called JNA. I only got as far as a proof of concept, but it should not be too difficult to work it into your project. Have a look here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/sebase/code/sebase-groovy/src/test/java/net/sourceforge/sebase/autoit Samples of usage is here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/sebase/code/sebase-groovy/src/test/groovy/net/sourceforge/sebase/demos/AutoItTest.groovy

Comment: Thanks! Tried it with JNA and it works perfectly.